# Can't connect to any port on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server

I have Ubuntu set up as a plex media server for many months now, yesterday after installing Samba, I now can't connect to any port using my other machines in the same network. From my windows machine, when I ping the the ip 192.169.100.77 it reaches but when I try to connect to 192.168.100.77:32400 or whichever ten ports for various things I have, it suddenly won't let me connect.

netstat -tpln

```
    (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.100.77:8324     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2342/qbittorrent    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6341          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2872/megasync       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6342          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2872/megasync       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45675         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6767            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2638/python3        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32401         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41371           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2651/anydesk        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8989            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1023/mono           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8125          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7070            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2651/anydesk        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19999           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44129         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::5de2:6deb:b8:8324 :::*                    LISTEN      2342/qbittorrent    
tcp6       0      0 :::7878                 :::*                    LISTEN      1018/Radarr         
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8686                 :::*                    LISTEN      1013/mono           
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2342/qbittorrent    
tcp6       0      0 :::32400                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9117                 :::*                    LISTEN      2361/./jackett      
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::19999                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::4545                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

netstat -rn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enxd03745e23bf5
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enxd03745e23bf5
```

iptables -nvL

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 570K  442M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT
 3505  309K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
45631 3283K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
45631 3283K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   26  1040 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
45594 3281K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 332K packets, 320M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
27095   35M ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 332K  320M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  enxd03745e23bf5 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      enxd03745e23bf5  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_post (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_pre (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_post (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_pre (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
45631 3283K IN_public  all  --  enxd03745e23bf5 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
45631 3283K IN_public_pre  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
45631 3283K IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
45631 3283K IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
45631 3283K IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
45629 3283K IN_public_post  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    9   708 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2    84 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_post (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_pre (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0f2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:46:5d:e9:16:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enxd03745e23bf5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:37:45:e2:3b:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.77/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enxd03745e23bf5
       valid_lft 84410sec preferred_lft 84410sec
    inet6 fe80::5de2:6deb:b8ea:5260/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: I have it difficult to imagine it could come from Samba installation.  Could you try and distable it, just to make sure? (`sudo service smbd stop`
`sudo service nmbd stop`

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the firewall while installing samba, purging it fixed my problem.